# How to extract the higher values in sql query

Tags: sql

I have a question about sql. If i have a table with some information like that:

```
  City       Code

New York      |  10A
New York      |  10A
New York      |  20A
L.A           |  20A
L.A           |  20A
Washington    |  30A 
Washington    |  30A 
Washington    |  20A 
San Francisco |  20A
San Francisco |  20A
```

with the query: `SELECT City, Code, COUNT(Code) FROM table GROUP BY City` I can get the following result:

```
 City         Code    Total

New York      |  10A     2
New York      |  20A     1
L.A           |  20A     2
Washington    |  30A     2
Washington    |  20A     1
San Francisco |  20A     2
```

The question is: How can I extract only the lines with higher total in each city?

Comment: Higher meaning? You have a threshold or you just want the top five in ascending order?

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: This is one area where different database engines offer different features, so you'll need to specify which one you're using. (PostgreSQL? MySQL? Oracle? SQL Server?)

Comment: Are you looking for the MAX Aggregate Function?
SELECT City, Code, MAX(Code) FROM table GROUP BY City

Comment: I need the top values. In this case should be new york 10A 2 - L.A 20A 2, Washington 30A 1 and San Francisco 20A 2

Answer (score 1):

Assuming SQL Server or a DBMS that has ranking functions:

```
SELECT * 
FROM  (SELECT City, Code,
              COUNT(Code) Count_, 
              RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY City ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) Rank_
       FROM  #test  
       GROUP BY City,Code
      ) sub
WHERE Rank_ = 1 ;
```

This will return all tying entries, for example in case of a 3-way tie for Denver, you'd get the following:

```
DEN 10A 1, DEN 20A 1, Den 30A 1
```

Tested in **[SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f6405/3)**. Works in Oracle, Postgres, SQL-Server.

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me:

```
SELECT     y.city, z.code, z.total
FROM       (SELECT city, MAX(total) AS total
            FROM (SELECT city, code, COUNT(code) AS total
                  FROM tableName
                  GROUP BY city, code) AS x
            GROUP BY city) AS y INNER JOIN
            (SELECT city, code, COUNT(code) AS total
             FROM tableName
             GROUP BY city, code) AS z
            ON y.city = z.city AND y.total = z.total
```

if there is a tie it will return all the rows that tied.

Comment: This approach would be appropriate if using MySQL or SQLite, I believe every other major RDBMS supports windowed functions, and they should be leveraged when possible, as it greatly simplifies this process.